# NServiceBus use type full name in EnclosedMessageTypes metadata

Tags: serialization, nservicebus, assembly-signing

NServiceBus includes meta Header with message "NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes".
It puts AssemblyQualifiedName of serialized type in there.

e.g.: `MyNamespance.MyType, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7777777777777777`

Can I make NServiceBus use just type FullName instead?

eg: `MyNamespance.MyType` instead of AssemblyQualifiedName.

Use Case:
Some legacy part of the system code requires assemblies signed. I don't want to sign all assemblies for this reason. So as a hack assemblies self signed only in legacy application. But when messages from shared contracts packages serialized in legacy application NServiceBus cannot deserialize them without signed assembly.

```
'NServiceBus.MessageDeserializationException: An error occurred while attempting to extract logical messages from transport message 99999999-9999-99999-9999-999999999999 ---&gt; Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Type specified in JSON 'MyNamespance.MyType, MyAssembly' was not resolved. Path '[0].$type', line 9, position 999.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in `IMutateTransportMessages` or more specifically in this case `IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages`

It allows changing headers, so I could strip PublicToken, so assembly looks unsigned.

```
public class EnclosedMessageTypeMutator : IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages
{
    public void MutateOutgoing(LogicalMessage logicalMessage, TransportMessage transportMessage)
    {
        var header = transportMessage.Headers["NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes"];
        header = header.Substring(0, header.LastIndexOf("=", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) + 1) + "null";
        transportMessage.Headers["NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes"] = header;
    }
}
```

And don't forget to register it:

```
   components.ConfigureComponent<EnclosedMessageTypeMutator>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
```

Comment: There's also this method available to register it:
`endpointConfiguration.RegisterMessageMutator(mutatorInstance);`